# makefile for a c program(on knoppix)

Tags: c, linux, makefile

i am currently trying to compile a program in c code using a makefile, the program copiles fine on windows in visual studio and i intend of course to make it work in my class enviorment(we use knoppix)

i created a makefile using a guide and this is the output:

```
knoppix@Microknoppix:~/Desktop/projfinal$ make
gcc -c main.c
make: Warning: File `q1.c' has modification time 8.2e+03 s in the future
gcc -c q1.c
gcc -c q2.c
gcc -c q3.c
gcc -c q4.c
gcc -c q5.c
gcc -c q6.c
gcc -c q7.c
gcc -o main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [runProject] Error 1
```

however i did add the file containing the main to the makefile for compiling, here is my makefile:

```
runProject: main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
    gcc -o main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o

main.o: main.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c main.c

q1.o: q1.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q1.c

q2.o: q2.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q2.c

q3.o: q3.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q3.c

q4.o: q4.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q4.c

q5.o: q5.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q5.c

q6.o: q6.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q6.c

q7.o: q7.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c q7.c

clean: 
    rm runProject main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
```

any assistance or insight would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you overriding so much of the standard boilerplate?

Comment: if i understand you well you mean im writing a lot of unnecesary syntax in my makefile? its because i only now learned how to do it and i did it from the internet, what would be a better way to do it?

Comment: make already knows how to build .o files; you only need to specify the header requirement. `q1.o: projectHeader.h` etc.

Comment: so for example i should write:
runProject: main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o

gcc -o main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o

main.o: main.c projectHeader.h

q1.o: projectHeader.h

q2.o: projectHeader.h

q3.o: projectHeader.h

q4.o: projectHeader.h

q5.o: projectHeader.h

q6.o: projectHeader.h

q7.o: projectHeader.h

clean: 

    rm runProject main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o

Comment: damn that not readible :|

Comment: You can also clean up the main.o rule as well since it looks for the same filename. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules

Comment: ok did that too, but i still have the error regarding the main

Comment: `gcc -o main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o` That looks wrong. Should be `gcc -o $@ main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o`. That is, need `-o` to be the target and not `main.o` which needs to be linked in.

Comment: thank you very much, i added a name for the exe file after -o and it indeed worked, i think im supposed to mark you as correct now but i cant find how

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can only mark *answers* as correct. Since @kaylum answered in a comment, you cannot mark it as correct until he composes an answer from it and posts it. Then, you will be able to mark it.

Comment: oh ok ^^, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the immediate question, this rule is just wrong:

```
runProject: main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
    gcc -o main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
```

The `-o` option to gcc sets the output file, so instead of linking with `main.o` here, you're trying to link an executable *called* `main.o` from all other object files. None of the other object files contains `main()`, this explains the linker error you get. A quick fix would be:

```
runProject: main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
    gcc -o runProject main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
```

This would create your executable called `runProject`.

---

There's a lot more to improve though. The *target* of a make rule should normally be a file that is created by that rule. Inside the rule, you have automatic variables available: `$@` for the target and `$<` or `$^` for the first resp. all prerequisites (the files after the colon, that are needed to create the output).

GNU make also supports pattern rules, using `%` as a wildcard for pattern matching, so there's no need at all to write the same rule over and over again.

Finally, targets that are NOT the name of created files should be declared `.PHONY`. Read the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) for details.

Suggested Makefile:

```
all: runProject

runProject: main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o
    gcc -o$@ $^

%.o: %.c projectHeader.h
    gcc -c -o$@ $<

clean: 
    rm -f runProject main.o q1.o q2.o q3.o q4.o q5.o q6.o q7.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i dont entirely understand this makefile but ill take the time and browse the manual some more, i did learn some interesting things about make thanks to the question, unfortunately asides from the issue of not giving make an executable name i will have to leave the rest as it was, i asked my proffessor and she insists i make it the way she taught so far(with the unneeded syntax and all :| ), aniways much appreciated and ill make sure to learn for next time ^^